# Permutation with repetition and subsets of a set

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

For the case when we consider permutations with repetition, for a set with n elements, from which we can arrange $r$ of them, the nr. of possible permutations is $n^r$.

Now lets consider 2 examples, which I believe use the above logic, for their results.

The first one is the case when we consider n elements, and each element can have one of two qualities at a time (we define 2 qualities that an element can have).Now I try to adjust or adopt (idk which would be the correct term to use) my situation, so that it resembles the situation defined for the permutations with repetition. Therefore I make the following arguments:
We have a set of 2 elements (the 2 qualities) and since we have repetition, I can pick r ($r \ge 2$) times from this set (r elements), therefore I find that the nr. of possible permutations with repetitions (also known as microstates) is $2^r$. For this example I simply want to know if my intuition, into getting the result, was correct? Did I adjusted my situation correctly, to that when one uses permutations with repetition?

Second example is that of the nr. of subsets of a set S with $n$ elements. An element can either be or not be in the subset. So each element has 2 qualities: 1- Yes it belongs to the subset, 2- No it does not. The rest of the argumentation is similar to the first example

Comment: Yes, both are correct... but I would discourage you from using the phrase "*permutations with repetition*" since the word "permutation" has very specific and strict meaning in algebra.  It has sadly been misappropriated to be used to mean any sort of arrangement of items though if we were to take the algebraic meaning it should only have been used to talk about arrangements without repetition and where every object available is used *exactly once* each, no more and no less.

Comment: It is worth also pointing out that while you said "*I can pick r ($r\geq 2$) times from this set*" there is actually no need to have that restriction.  $r$ can be any non-negative integer including zero and one and this still make sense.

Comment: I see. But when you want to have an arrangement but there can be elements that are the same that can be used more then once, what do you call that?

Comment: I personally just use the generic term... *arrangement*.  I may also use a more descriptive term such as "*string*" or "*sequence*" if either fits the scenario well enough.  If repetition is or isn't allowed and I wish to emphasize this, I would say so as well as part of the description.  That all being said, there are many out there who are comfortable using the word permutation in the way you had despite such objections... language is fluid after all.

Comment: One further question, which is in the realm for combinatorics and permutation. One can speak about permutations and combinations with distinguishable objects. We can also speak about permutations with indistinguishable elements, but can we also talk about combinations with indistinguishable elements?

Comment: See [The Twelvefold Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way) for the twelve most common counting problems, commonly presented by being described as problems about number of ways of putting balls in boxes with various combinations of restrictions (*balls distinguishable/indistinguishable, boxes distinguishable/indistinguishable, at least one per box, at most one per box*).  What you ask about is one of these.

Comment: Another suggestion: remember the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product). The number of ways to choose among two options $r$ times is $2\times\dots\times2=2^r$.

Comment: thank you for the explanation